# Install drivers for Intel integrated GPU in Ubuntu 18.04 for DaVinci Resolve 17?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, integrated, davinci-resolve

My GPU is this

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I have installed DaVinci Resolve 17 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, but when starting resolve it shows Unsupported GPU Mode error.

[image]

Then in configuration it shows no GPU to select.

[image]

I have seen this command for Nvidia `sudo apt install nvidia-driver nvidia-opencl-icd libcudal libnvidia-encodel`, but it doesn't work for this iGPU. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the hardware is not up to the task. You need to use a supported GPU. https://www.richardlackey.com/davinci-resolve-system-requirements/

Comment: `apt-get install intel-opencl-icd` should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but installing the latest intel-cl drivers as described on the developer-page helped:
https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/blob/master/opencl/doc/DISTRIBUTIONS.md
Cheers
M

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for your answer.  We try to discourage "link-only" answers here, so I'd ask that you try to include at least a *summary* of the steps you performed.  Looking at the Github page you linked, it seems like the Ubuntu 18.04 (per the question) instructions are only three lines anyway, so it really doesn't make sense *not* to include them here.

Comment: worked on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Just install `sudo apt install intel-opencl-icd`

Comment: Link broken. Here's a link to the old version: https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/blob/6d2b0c722e5977e1efdf5eeb32f51f5efada9787/opencl/doc/DISTRIBUTIONS.md

Answer (score 3):

**DaVinci Resolve Minimum System Requirements**

**GPU memory**

- 512MB – Forget about it
- 1GB – You’ll be okay with basic HD ProRes work, checking RAW files but avoid noise reduction and optical flow.
- 1.5GB – Approaching the absolute minimum to use Resolve with some level of complexity in HD. Noise reduction and optical flow will still be problematic. I’ve made a 1.5GB Intel Iris Pro GPU work well on a iMac and Macbook Pro, and manage to render a full 4K delivery.
- 2GB – A comfortable HD experience, limited 4K work.
- 4GB – Minimum for comfortable 4K work.
- 6GB – You can tackle pretty much everything a project is likely to require.
- 8GB+ – You can actually tackle everything any project is likely to require.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Double check what hardware you actually have.

Intel graphics are integrated.  If you don't have a dedicated GPU, that means that your CPU is also your iGPU.

If you're currently operating a desktop environment, then your graphics drivers are already installed and working.

If you didn't have a working iGPU or a GPU you would not be able to use a desktop environment.

Furthermore, unless you have a NVIDIA GPU, you have no use for NVIDIA graphics cards' drivers.  In fact, if you forced the installation with incompatible hardware, you could very well break your system.

I don't know anything about your application, but it suggests to me that you may have set a wrong setting in that application. If you do not have a dedicated GPU and you are supposed to choose between CPU and GPU processing, you must probably select CPU.

After a quick search from my favorite search engine using the terms "DaVinci Resolve 17 minimum system requirements", it seems to suggest that a dedicated GPU is a requirement to run the software.

Comment: The desktop will work without OpenCL, Resolve won't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain (but can't seem to find documentation) that Davinci Resolve *requires* an Nvidia GPU with the proprietary drivers. Unfortunately, if you don't have one, you can't run it.

Comment: This is sort-of true in a practical sense, but not actually true.  They sai that a discrete GPU is required on Linux, but this is just a way of saying they don't *support* integrated GPUs on Linux - but they can be made to work, as per the packages listed in other answers.  AMD graphics cards can also be coaxed into working, (I am using AMD on Linux).  Either way, things have to be set up just right.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu Studio 23.04 on HP running Intel CPU and had the same issue with Resolve not opening. I was able to install intel open cl using Synaptic Package Manager and now Resolve opens! [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxhPS.jpg)